# How can i set views filter to show specific content based on actual month?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

The content that i want to show is random pictures in views block. Few of them needs to by shown on January, others on February, others on March, and so on.

Showing of specific content will reapeats every year (example: only in january in every year)

I have created vocabulary for that content type with "January", "February", "March" as values. Every photo has one of these values.
And now is the part where i am stuck:

I want to add views filter which points to that vocabulary with additional actual date rule, like:

IF date('m') = january THEN set filter to Vocabulary Months = January else

IF date('m) = february THEN set filter to Vocabulary Months = February ... and so on.

Can someone tell me by wich modules i will achieve this?

I did this already by using [Date Repeat module](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_repeat_entity) but for user it means, that he needs to put some extra values in 3-4 additional fields - and that is "not simple".

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'd switch from a taxonomy field to a date field (i.e. set month as a date field value on the images), then use [the current relative date as a filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/186389).